# how to redirect to a different component when clicking on an external url in Reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

I have to create a kind of news web app. I'm using NewsAPI.org to make API calls.I have a list of news channels in one page and clicking on any one channel should render specific content from that news channel on another page. I have some information on using react-router but I guess that is not used while dealing with the external domain urls. I'm not able to figure out how to implement this. I have used axios here.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import { fetchSourceList } from '../actions';

class SourceList extends Component{

  componentDidMount(){
     this.props.fetchSourceList();
  }

  renderList(){
   let {lists} = this.props;
   let returnHTML = [];
   for(let key in lists){
     lists[key].map((item)=>{
       returnHTML.push(
        <li className="list-group-item" key={item.id}>
            <a href={item.url}>{ item.name }</a>
        </li>
       );
     });
   }
   return returnHTML;
}

  render(){
    return (
      <div>
         <ul className = "list-group">
         <li className = "list-group-item text-light bg-dark"><h3>Sources</h3></li>
           {this.renderList()}
         </ul>
      </div>

    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state){
  return { lists: state.sourceList };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchSourceList })(SourceList);
```

Comment: What is the exact problem that you are facing

Comment: Can you please give some explanation that what is the problem you are facing while what you want to achieve?

Comment: Sounds to me you need a route to a new page on click, with some id, f.x. using React router, and then on your new page you could use componentDidMount as in this example to fetch data and put it in the Redux as you also have used here.

Comment: The thing that I want to achieve exactly is, on clicking {item.name} (which indeed is a name of a news channel like BBC news), I should be redirected to a different component and in that component I have to display top headlines from that news channel (like top headlines of BBC news).

Comment: And in your case you are redirected to different webpage altogether??

Comment: @Kunukn
Yes, I want something of this sort only.

Comment: @Shubham Khatri Yes, I'm being redirected to a different webpage on clicking any link but this is not what I want.

Comment: you don't want to redirect to another page but want to display a different thing on button click is that correct ?

Comment: @aravind_reddy Yes, I want to display different page on clicking the link, rather than the default one.

Comment: then you should try conditional display but that wont be good bcz if you want to go back to previous state then you cant

Answer (score 0):

You **have** to use a router as follow:

```
/news/:type
```

Where **news** is a *route* and **type** is a *param*.

In *news* route you'll render always the same component to render the API response, while you'll use *type* params to switch channel and feed the service you use for fetching API's. This will allow also a user to copy/paste a channel url, or bookmark it.

Comment: Thank You. It really helped!